# JQuery последовательность библиотек

Tags: jquery, php

В моем проекте билиотеки JQuery используют меню и изображения (http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=238). Но при запуске всего FancyBox отказывается работать. Может я не правильно указал последовательность?
Меню

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://grimon.net/css/jqueryslidemenu.css" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
```

Изображения

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Comment: Откройте исходный код страницы и понажимайте по ссылкам с подключаемыми файлами скриптов и стилей, самый простой способ убедиться что файлы подключились или нет :)

Answer (score 1):

Библиотеки jQuery всегда должны подключаться после самого jQuery. Думаю, что-то неправильно сделано.

А библиотеки точно подключаются?

Answer (score 1):

1 Проверьте правильность путей до плагинов (.js .css).

2 Проверьте что в .css для плагинов верно указаны пути для изображений (иногда директории с ними склыдавают в другое место и изза этого не работает)